# Issue in Cross Compiling for powerpc Maliit framework

Tags: c++, c, qt, cross-compiling

Facing issues in cross compiling maliit framework source code.

```
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp: In member function 'virtual void Maliit::InputContext::DBus::DynamicAddress::get()':
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp:50: error: 'QDBusMessage' was not declared in this scope
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp:50: error: expected ';' before 'message'
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp:52: error: 'message' was not declared in this scope
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp:54: error: 'QDBusConnection' has not been declared
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp: In member function 'void Maliit::InputContext::DBus::DynamicAddress::successCallback(const QDBusVariant&)':
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const struct QDBusVariant'
inputcontextdbusaddress.h:21: error: forward declaration of 'const struct QDBusVariant'
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp: In member function 'void Maliit::InputContext::DBus::DynamicAddress::errorCallback(const QDBusError&)':
inputcontextdbusaddress.cpp:67: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'const struct QDBusError'
inputcontextdbusaddress.h:22: error: forward declaration of 'const struct QDBusError'
```

Already check for circular dependency and it including QDBus also. Every thing looking good. If anyone faced such issues please let me know or share your thought how we can fixed this issue

Comment: Check again your circular dependency, your includes, etc.. It's impossible to give you a solution with only these errors. Try to compile as minimum as possible files to check where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem myself. Problem comes because QtDBus module does not enabled. 
For enabling QtDBus module you need to run configure with -dbus

./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-powerpc-g++ -dbus ......

But before enable you should have libdbus-1 otherwise you will get below message.

The QtDBus module cannot be enabled because libdbus-1 version 0.93 was not found.
Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to ./configure to see the final report.
If you believe this message is in error you may use the continue
switch (-continue) to ./configure to continue.

For that you should download dbus-1.2.4.6.tar.gz and expat-2.0.1.tar.gz

1. cross-compile expat

   - tar zxvf expat-2.0.1.tar.gz
   - cd expat-2.0.1/
   - ./configure --host=powerpc-linux --prefix=/usr/local/expat/  CC=powerpc-linux-gcc
   - make;
   - make install
2. cross-compile dbus

   - tar zxvf dbus-1.2.24.tar.gz
   - cd dbus-1.2.24
   - ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/dbus/ --host=powerpc-linux --with-x=no ac_cv_have_abstract_sockets=yes "CC=powerpc-linux-gcc  -I/usr/local/expat/include -L/usr/local/expat/lib"
   - make;
   - make install;
3. cross-compile Qt with dbus

   - export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/dbus/lib/pkgconfig
   - configure with  " -dbus " and " -force-pkg-config "